# How to control the execution timing of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

When user click search button, reset current page to 1, and set filter object, and then call fetch function. 
The projectId is a global variable, when it's changed, need to reset page and filter, and reload data. 
useEffect require dependence of fetch function, but when fetch function change, it will re-execute fetch function. 
**How can I deal with this logic and not to trigger any warning of eslint?**
*Sorry, my English is not good.*

```
const fetch = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    // Call the request function passed in from the outside
    const { data, total } = await request({ current: currPage }, filter);
    setList(data);
    setTotal(total);
    setLoading(false);
  }, [currPage, filter, request]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrPage(1);
    setFilter({});
    fetch();
  }, [fetch, projectId]);
```

Comment: "When user click search button". - What button are you referring to? Does anything else in the code need to call `fetch`? If not you can move it inside the `useEffect` hook's callback and remove it as a dependency. I have the suspicion you've not included all the relevant code you're working with and have an issue with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to keep fetch in the dependency array of useEffect  When the projectId changes you will change the currPage & filter which will automatically trigger the useEffect which has the fetch() function in it.

```
const fetch = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    // Call the request function passed in from the outside
    const { data, total } = await request({ current: currPage }, filter);
    setList(data);
    setTotal(total);
    setLoading(false);
  }, [currPage, filter, request]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrPage(1);
    setFilter({});
    fetch();
  }, [projectId]);
```

I suggested this code serves the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but remove fetch from dependencies will trigger an eslint warning. I wonder if this can be ignored？When projectId changed, current page and filter will change, fetch funciton will execute twice, how can I handle this?

Comment: You can set both currPage and filter in one useState only giving keys currentPage, filter in object.  Ex: const [obj,setObj] = useState({ filter: {}, currPage: 0}); Then for both of them you set at once & can reduce dependencies.